# How to get VSCode to attach to nodemon started by NPM?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, babeljs, nodemon

Can I have VSCode kick off my app using NPM run scripts and then attach to the resulting process to debug?

My project kicks off with nodemon via NPM script (to execute babel, etc). However, while the app kicks off, VSCode's debugger doesn't attach (breakpoints are skipped).

// from package.json

```
"scripts": { "debug": "nodemon --inspect --exec babel-node src/app.js" }
```

// from launch.json

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script",
        "debug"
      ],
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 9229,
      "protocol": "auto",
      "restart": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
    }
```

It seems the debugger starts but breakpoints I placed next to a few test calls are ignored. Here's the terminal output:

````
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node --inspect src/app.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/13ef6ca8-40da-4741-854a-467e4230b2a7
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Hey!
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart```
````

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was a fool's errand because it technically can't be done.

Comment: I've been trying to get it to work with no luck so I guess it makes sense, although it's very disappointing. Can you please share where did you read that it's technically impossible?

Comment: Because I've managed to get a bug open with the VSCode folks: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80019

(I should have been more specific, my apologies.)